# Why does this :id in Rails not work with Postgresql but it does work with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am using this method for search engine friendly URLs in Rails - http://jroller.com/obie/entry/seo_optimization_of_urls_in

My model looks like this.

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    "#{id}-#{title.parameterize}"
  end
end
```

This works with MySQL but not Postgresql.

This is the error I get:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "16-    college-station-apartments"
: SELECT * FROM "floorplans" WHERE ("floorplans"."listing_id" = E'16-college-station-apartments')  ORDER BY beds ASC, baths ASC, footage ASC, price ASC):

Is ActiveRecord not doing a .to_i on the find for Postgresql?

Comment: im not sure the problem is in the code you have posted ... maybe in your controller or migration ... anyway , for managing slugs i will suggest you to try friendly_id gem or stringex. have  a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails will automatically call `to_i` on your parameter for **some** methods, mainly those where an integer is expected as a parameter, like `Listing.find(params[:id])`.

However, for other types of search methods that can accept strings as parameters, you'll need to manually call `to_i`

```
Listing.find_by_id(params[:id].to_i)
Listing.find(:conditions => ["id = ?", params[:id].to_i])
```

The reason you're not having a problem with MySQL is that MySQL does what would in effect be a `to_i` on its end (i.e. it's not a database-adapter issue, but rather a capability of the actual database server).

Comment: I think this is incorrect; I had a controller call find(params[:id]) and got the same error with a user-entered URL. There's no .to_i anywhere in 3.0.9's ActiveRecord finder_methods.rb.  Maybe Rails used to do this, but no longer does, and nobody noticed because MySQL is so popular?