# Heroku + Rails Error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku

I'm having a bit of a dilemma here.

I have a Comments scaffold and a Movies scaffold

When going to a movie page and creating a new comment, i go here /movies/12/comments/new (12 being the id)

And did is my controller

```
def new
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
    @comment = @movie.comments.new 
    @search = Movie.search(params[:q])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @comment }
    end
  end
```

But when i launch to heroku I get this error

```
*Processing by CommentsController#new as HTML
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "movie_id"

 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 636ms
LINE 1: ...  "movies".* FROM "movies"  WHERE "movies"."id" = 'movie_id'...

Parameters: {"movie_id"=>"the-social-network"}
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:99:in `load_movie'*
```

I tried removing the `@movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])` or adding `.to_i` at the end, as stated here [Why does this :id in Rails not work with Postgresql but it does work with MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122762/why-does-this-id-in-rails-not-work-with-postgresql-but-it-does-work-with-mysql), but still no luck

Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Comment_form (view)

```
<%= simple_form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :subject %>
    <%= f.input :body %>
    <%= f.input :movie_id %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Movie.rb

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title


 has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy

      extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :titleyear, use: :history
  def titleyear
    "#{title} #{id}"
  end

end
```

Comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :movie_id, :subject, :user_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :movie




end
```

Comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /comments
  # GET /comments.json
  before_filter :load_movie
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new,:create,:edit,:destroy]



  def index
    @comments = @movie.comments.all
    @search = Movie.search(params[:q])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @comments }
    end
  end

  # GET /comments/1
  # GET /comments/1.json
  def show
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @search = Movie.search(params[:q])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @comment }
    end
  end

  # GET /comments/new
  # GET /comments/new.json
  def new
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
    @comment = @movie.comments.new 
    @search = Movie.search(params[:q])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @comment }
    end
  end

  # GET /comments/1/edit
  def edit
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @search = Movie.search(params[:q])

  end

  # POST /comments
  # POST /comments.json
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    @search = Movie.search(params[:q])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to :back }
        format.json { render json: @comment, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /comments/1
  # PUT /comments/1.json
  def update
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @search = Movie.search(params[:q])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.update_attributes(params[:comment])
        format.html { redirect_to (@movie), notice: 'Comment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /comments/1
  # DELETE /comments/1.json
  def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to comments_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

private
    def load_movie
      @movie = Movie.find_by_id(:movie_id)
    end


end
```

Comment: It appears that `movie_id` is actually "the-social-network" which is not an integer.

Comment: Can you post your view? The problem more than likely resides in your form.

Comment: Your view looks correct, but it's unusual that `:movie_id` is passing a URL-type string, rather than an id-type integer. Can you post both the `Movie` and `Comment` models?

Comment: Ok added the two files

Comment: Can you confirm you're visiting a URL like `http://hostname/movies/12/comments/new`, and not something like `http://hostname/the-social-network/comments/new`?

Comment: 2013-06-11T20:46:23.804299+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/movies/the-social-network/comments/new host=www.example.com fwd="00.000.000.000" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1335ms status=500 bytes=643

Comment: I changed the code for safety and confidential reasons


Example.com is the domain name
and 00.000.000.000 is my ip

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31614/discussion-between-zeantsoi-and-user2225129)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `movie_id` parameter, as you're passing it, is not actually an `id`, but a string: `Parameters: {"movie_id"=>"the-social-network"}`.

Something is probably misconfigured in your view. Ensure that you're passing the `movie.id` and not something else.

EDIT:

The error being received is indicating that the string `the-social-network` is being passed from the `movie_id` URL segment. You need to access your form by visiting a path that passes in a number as the second parameter, like `http://yoursite/movies/2/comments/new`, rather than `http://yoursite/movies/the-social-network/comments/new`.

Comment: Ok so how would i change movie_id to pass a parameter instead?

Comment: Hmm... can you go into your Rails console and post an example of an existing `Comment` object? I'd be interested to see what the `movie_id` attribute is. From command line, type `rails console`, then `Comment.first`. Comment back with what it returns.

Comment: Comment Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" LIMIT 1
 => #<Comment id: 1, subject: "Test Comment", body: "THis is a test comment, movie_id: 21, created_at: "2013-06-06 16:20:15", updated_at: "2013-06-06 16:20:47", user_id: nil>

Comment: One last thing: can you post your `create` action for your `comments_controller.rb`? I think we're close to isolating the issue...